# How can i implement concurrency in C like we do in go?

Tags: c, go, concurrency

I would like to implement go's concurrency in C because I have seen that it increases the [performance] of go. I have not tried anything because I can't understand what to try.  How can I do that?

Comment: What is the pattern that you would like to implement in C?

Comment: C11 added concurrency to C, but those facilities are not widely implemented.  Otherwise, your choices are platform-specific. Which platform are you targeting?

Comment: I want to target all the platform

Comment: Do you particularly aim to implement coroutines, multithreading or other kind of concurrency/parallelism?

Comment: I want to know how to implement coroutines.

Comment: [coroutines in C example](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coroutines are not available in C natively (although they're supported in C++ starting with C++20), so you're going to rely on external libraries or you'll have to implement something yourself.

Some useful resources: [an example by Simon Tatham](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/coroutines.html), [another small example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coroutines-in-c-cpp), [a C library called `libaco`](https://github.com/hnes/libaco), [an interesting article with an alternative approach](http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/coroutine-in-c-language).

Another approach could be using an event-loop, that is the same approach used by JavaScript to implement concurrency within a single thread. One of the most used libraries is [`libuv`](https://libuv.org) and [here's a small example of using `libuv`](https://linuxjedi.co.uk/2020/04/28/event-loop-programming-a-different-way-of-thinking).